# Downgrade from Windows 10 to windows 8.1 impossible

Tags: windows-10

Its only some days that I upgraded to Windows 10, but it does not work so well, so I want to upgrade again later, but the problem is that I can't downgrade from the option return to Win 8.1 (available for one month), but when I try it says that the files necessary to downgrade were removed from this PC, but I checked, and the folder C:Windows.old (necessary for the downgrade) is still present.

What can I do ?

Can I downgrade manually trough the Windows.old folder ?
Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: Try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/220723/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-downgrade-to-windows-7-or-8.1/

Answer (score 2):

The old version of the OS remains stored in a "Windows.old" folder. This folder allows you to restore that previous version directly from Windows 10.

To do so, simply click on the Windows Start menu at the bottom left of the screen and access Settings > Update & Security > Recovery.you'll see an option to "Go back to Windows 8.1" . Then select "Get started" to the downgrade process.

However, this downgrade option will be available only for one month since installing Windows 10.

After that, you may also want to consider installing a rollback tool like [Easeus System GoBack](http://www.easeus.com/system-go-back/). Because rollback option expires after one month. GoBack should work indefinitely.